# Python/Outlook Attachment: "cannot find this file..verify exists"

Tags: python, outlook, glob, pywin32

I wrote the following to use Outlook to send an email, but it is not able to locate the file I want to reference:

```
import win32com.client as win32
import glob
import os
import datetime

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'xx@ii.ca'
mail.Subject = 'Message subject'
mail.Body = 'Message body'
mail.HTMLBody = '<h2>HTML Message body</h2>'# this field is optional

#In case you want to attach a file to the email

newestfile  = max(glob.iglob('*.csv'), key=os.path.getctime))
mail.Attachments.Add(newestfile)

mail.Send()
```

if i try to `print(max(glob.iglob('*.csv'), key=os.path.getctime)))` it returns the right path. Directly writing the path in `newestfile` also works fine. How come it doesn't attach in its current form?

I also tried converting the path to a string, that did not work

Comment: what does `print(max(glob.iglob('*.csv'), key=os.path.getctime)))` actually print?

Comment: `smgon.csv`, let me try appending the full path in the beginning of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Attachments.Add Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/attachments-add-method-outlook) docs, the first argument is:

> The source of the attachment. This can be a file (represented by the
>   full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that
>   constitutes the attachment.